# After "noun and/or noun", do I have to use "have" or "has"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The relative importance and/or fairness among users (has/have) not been addressed.

For "and", "have" is correct, but for "or", "has" is correct.
Which is the correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people would say that 'and/or' is not standard English. Many style guides advise avoiding its use. 'A and/or B' is logically equivalent to 'A or B or both'. Since 'both' is plural, we would follow 'and/or' with a plural verb.

Grammar Girl agrees: [And/or (Grammargirl)](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/andor)

Also see here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134703/using-a-singular-or-plural-verb-after-and-or

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I was always confused about and/or usage.